# How to Deserialize binary protobuf to json with bash script

Tags: json, bash, protocol-buffers, proto, protoc

I have developed a bash script to deserialize binary protobuf to json but output is look like json but no true json

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
...
binaryMsg= ..
echo binaryMsg > /tmp/di.bin

protoc --decode=my.proto.PkgDiStatus controller.proto</tmp/di.bin
```

it gives output like below

```
ups_status {
  low_battery: false
  no_power_out: false
  replace_battery: false
  common_fault: false
}
testing_mode: false
```

I have to extract values of **low_battery** or **replace_batter**, Although this output can be parse with custom script like sed but if i get json then jq can be use for parsing.

Comment: This output is not json.

Comment: @Marco Yes I know it's not JSON, that my question is how I can get it as a JSON?

Comment: Okay, I see. I have no experience with this. I guess you found this already: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbjs

Comment: Mind sharing the Bash script you used for deserializing?